# MVC JavaScript patterns

Tags: javascript

I tried to make the task of patterns, but it's does not works. I need to pass this task , here's what I got, and the task is below. I will be grateful if somebody can help me.

```js
window.onload = function() {

//--------MODEL---------------
//*
function Model(option) {
 this.name = option.name;
 this.age = option.age;
 this.year = option.year;
 this.examsTaken = option.examsTaken;
};

Model.prototype = {
 constructor: Model,
 takeExam:function(){
  this.examsTaken++;
  this.changed = true;
 }
}

// -----CONTROLLER -------------
//*
function Controller(action){
 this.model = action.model;
 this.elementId = action.elementId;

};

Controller.prototype = {
 constructor: Controller,
 render: function(){
  return '<span>' + this.model.name + '</span><button id="student-exams-button">Increase exams taken</button>';
 },
 clickHandlers: {
  '#student-exams-button': 'updateExams'
 },
 updateExams: function(){
  this.model.takeExam();
 }
};

//--------VIEW------------
function View() {
 document.getElementById(StudentController.elementId).innerHTML = StudentController.render();

}
//---INFORMATION ---

var Student = new Model({
 name: 'Piotr',
 age: 22,
 year: 5,
 examsTaken: 2,
});

var StudentController = new Controller({
 model: Student,
 elementId: 'student-container'
});

View();

//test
console.log(StudentController.render());
Student.takeExam();
StudentController.updateExams()
console.log(Student.examsTaken);
StudentController.updateExams()
console.log(Student.examsTaken);


  }
```

and the task is...

Implement pattern MVC / MVP by implementing entities Model and Controller / Presenter. View presented in the form of html. 
Model keeps data and processing methods, and Controller - handles the events from the user and renders the view.
Thus, as a result of the following code should work as expected:

```js
var Student = new Model({
    name: 'Piotr',
    age: 22,
    year: 5,
    examsTaken: 2,
    takeExam: function(){
        this.examsTaken++;
        this.changed = true;
    }
});
var StudentController = new Controller({
    model: Student,
    elementId: 'student-container',
    render: function(){
        return '<span>' + this.model.name + '</span><button id="student-exams-button">Increase exams taken</button>';
    },
    clickHandlers: {
        '#student-exams-button': 'updateExams'
    },
    updateExams: function(){
        this.model.takeExam();
    }
});
```

Therefore, Model does not have any special logic is essentially a mere object. Controller also inserts the result in the render 
function found element with an id of properties elementId. Render is called when a Controller. It is also necessary to realize 
the essence of the method of Controller, which will check every 100ms this.model.changed and if it is true, call the method render, 
changed and returned to false. (This is an extremely abhorrent practice, but is useful for you to understand what will happen next) values ​​
of the object are methods clickHandlers Controller, which will be called when the user clicks on an element key to the current value

Comment: This looks like a good writeup of your homework assignment, but _"it's does not works"_ is not a good writeup of your problem... Where specifically are you stuck? We won't do your homework for you on StackOverlflow, but we will help you answer a specific question that has you stuck on doing your own homework.

Comment: This looks like your entire assignment, we're not gonna solve this for you. It exists so that you should learn, after all. If you're having problems with MVC, read up on it. If you're having a specific issue, post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, so maybe somebody will need answer

```
function Model(obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
                this[key] = obj[key];
        }
}

function Controller(obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
                this[key] = obj[key];
        }

        document.getElementById(this.elemetId).innerHTML = this.render(); 
        this.setHandlers();
        this.checkModelChanges();
}

  Controller.prototype.setHandlers = function () {
        var that = this;

        document.getElementById(that.elemetId).onclick = function (e) {
                var id = '#' + e.srcElement.getAttribute('id'),
                        handler = that.clickHandlers[id];
                if (handler) {
                        that[handler].call(that);
                }
        };
};

Controller.prototype.checkModelChanges = function () {
        var that = this;

        setInterval(function () {
                if (that.model.changed) {
                        document.getElementById(that.elemetId).innerHTML = that.render(); 
                        that.model.changed = false;
                }
        }, 100);
};
```